# What is the proper way of add cache value on ionic-cache?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-storage

I tried to read the https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache readme, but I cant understand how to store value on it.

I tried to put `this.cache.getOrSetItem('key', 'value')`, but I am just getting this error  `Argument of type '"value"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CacheValueFactory<{}>'. (typescript-tide)` and got no idea what is `CacheValueFactory`.

Somebody can point please, for best documentation about this if there is any.

Thanks.

P.S. Just trying to learn Ionic framework.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, I think you are trying to get or set values and store in app memory. I suggest you could change your plugin to [Ionic Native Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/). It is easy and simpler to user.
The stored data will clear only if you clear data or cache on your mobile app settings or use `clear()`/`remove()` methods in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `this.cache.saveItem(key: string, data: any, groupKey?: string, ttl?: number) : Promise<any>`

Where `this.cache.saveItem('myUniqueCacheKey', 'mySavedResponseValueMayBeJSON')` is a simple example.

`this.cache.getOrSetItem` is to use when one is uncertain about the existance of a cached key, and one wants it to be written, if it does not exist. To understand what needs to be written one needs to build a `CacheValueFactory`. That is another topic though.